# Implement a rule in prolog called "stepWith", that takes three parameters, a list L and two integers i and j

Tags: prolog

Implement a rule called "stepWith", that takes three parameters,
       a list L and two integers i and j.  The rule returns true, if the
       value i can be "stepped" into the value j, using only legal "steps".
       The list L provides a set of integers that make up the legal steps.

```
   For example, stepWith([7,12,19],6,32) would return true, because,
   starting at 6, there exists at least one sequence of additions using
   only the numbers in the list (7, 3, and 12), producing 28.  Namely:
   6+7+7+12 = 32.

   By contrast, stepWith([7,12,19],6,31) would be an example that should
   return false, since there is no sequence of additions starting from 6,
   and using only the values 7, 12, and 19, that results in 31.

   Make sure that your rule works for various values, and various size
   lists for L.  You can assume that all of the integers are positive,
   and that i is less than j.

 *** CLARIFICATION ***

   The value i, in the above description, can only be included in
   the addition once, at the very beginning.  The numbers in the 
   list L can be used as many times as necessary (or zero times).
```

this is what i have so far but its just goes through the first element of the list and subtracts it until it reaches 0. I need it to go through each element to find the combination that to get to the given value.

```
stepWith(L,I,J) :- Z is J-I, step(L,Z).

step([F|L],Z) :- N1 is Z - F, goThrough(N1,L).
step([],0).

goThrough(X,[X|Y]).
goThrough(X,[M|N]) :- goThrough(X,N).
```

Comment: Your question is not specific to SWI, so don't use that tag.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite get why you introduce that `goThrough` predicate.

Without that you almost got the solution, just two things to correct:

- step(A,0) is true for whatever A you get, not only the empty list (because of the rules you describe, when you reach 0, it does not matter if there are some numbers you havent tried).
- recurse step in two ways, by passing just `L`, and by passing `[F|L]`, meaning that if you tried one number, you don't use it anymore, or you can use it more times.

Here a possible solution:

```
stepWith(L,I,J) :- Z is J-I, step(L,Z).

step(_,0).
step([F|L],Z) :- Z > 0, step(L,Z).
step([F|L],Z) :- Z > 0, Z1 is Z-F, step([F|L],Z1).
```

Note that I also added `Z > 0` to guarantee **universal termination**. If you remove `Z > 0`, then the order of predicates becomes important, and if you move the base case after the recursive rules, you can get non-terminating behavior. (as an exercise, try to remove it and experiment yourself, since you are learning Prolog anyway :-)).